# Select as table_name

Tags: oracle

From MySQL and SQL Server, I know that I can "save" selected as table like:

```
Select * (Select * from Table) as tb.
```

I tried it in Oracle with the following:

```
Select Firma, Nr,Tour from(  SELECT
  fahr.FIRMA FIRMA,
  fahr.nr nr,
  fahr.TOUR,
  fahr.ausf_tag ausf_tag,
  fahr.kunde kunde,
  fahrp.artikel artikel,
  fah.bezeichnung,
  fa.fraktion_nr,
  fahrp.eak_nr eak_nr,
  fahrp.auftr_nr auftragsnummer,
  fahrp.auftr_pos auftragsposition,
  fahrp.auftr_upos auftragsunterposition,
  NULL tourgewicht,
  fahr.leistgort leistgort,
  fahr.lo_gpname1 lo_gpname1,
  fahr.lo_strasse lo_strasse,
  fahr.lo_plz lo_plz,
  fahr.lo_ort lo_ort,
  fahr.fzg_nr,
  fahr.pol_kennz,
  fahrzfa.eigner,
  TO_CHAR (fahr.start_zeit, 'HH24:MI:SS') start_zeit,
  TO_CHAR (fahr.ende_zeit, 'HH24:MI:SS') ende_zeit,
  fahr.kilometer,
  fahr.Warenlager,
  fahrp.Warenlager LAGER,
  fahr.TOUR,
  fahrp.KTR KTR,
  fahr.faktura,
  fahrp.rechnung faktura_pos,
  fahr.abrechnung,
  fahr.standort,
  fahr.standort2,
  skp_AUFTRAG_EK.rg_empf,
  skp_AUFTRAG_EK.rg_empf_kz,
  fahrp.preis_ueberschrieben,
  skp_auftrag_ek.ds_branche,


FROM

  skp_ARTIKEL_WARE_Z fa,
  skp_ARTIKEL_Z fah,
  skp_FAHRAUFTRAG fahr,
  skp_FAHRAUFTRAG_POS fahrp,
  skp_FAHRZEUG fahrzfa,
  skp_FIRMA fahrfir,
  skp_AUFTRAG_EK

WHERE

  fahr.FIRMA       = fahrp.FIRMA
AND fahr.nr        = fahrp.nr
AND fahrp.FIRMA    = skp_AUFTRAG_EK.FIRMA(+)
AND fahrp.auftr_nr = skp_AUFTRAG_EK.auftr_nr(+)
AND fahrp.artikel  = fah.art_nr
AND fahr.FIRMA     = fahrzfa.FIRMA(+)
AND fahr.fzg_nr    = fahrzfa.fzg_nr(+)
And Fahr.Firma     = Fahrfir.Firma
and fahrp.artikel  = fa.art_nr(+)
and fahr.firma     between 721 and 778
and fahr.ausf_tag  >= to_date ('01.09.2017 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and fahr.ausf_tag  <= to_date ('30.09.2017 00:00:00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) as d
```

But i doesn't work, I get the error: 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

I new to Oracle and not a SQL god so does anyone know whats wrong???

Comment: Why are you selecting all columns within the inner select when you only need three columns?.. And get rid off Oracle's JOIN syntax..Oracle themselves recommend that you not use the (+) notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear here - you have duplicate column name in your `SELECT`. From what I see, it's the `TOUR` column - but please double check, as there might be other duplicates too. As a general rule, always use aliases for **all** columns when doing `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`

Comment: I would go so far as to say "...always use aliases for all columns..." and not qualify it.  Just always use table aliases on columns.  Your future self will thank you, when you go and look at code that is months or years old.